Ubuntu not booting correctly after update to 24.04 and kernel 6.8
After updating to Ubuntu 24.04, it doesn't boot correctly with kernel 6.8.0.49-generic.  It fully works with kernel 5.15.0-126-generic, however.
Initially, it would hang trying to start systemd-journald.service, but after masking systemd-journald.service on kernel 5, it repeats this message around 20 times before finishing booting and once it's finished, it has several issues including the USB mouse not working & hanging on shutdown.
acpi command f5/00.00.00.00.00.00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out

